# xdebug not seeing class variables

Tags: eclipse, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

i got xdebug to work with netbeans and eclipse, but i am seeing only variables declared in the function, not on the class/object level. $this is not present in the displayed variables. i cant figure out what setting i should change on xdebug?

Comment: Post a screen-shot of your variables-view(-tab) from debug-perspective and a c&p of the xdebug-section from phpinfo-output.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your xdebug PHP module - this sounds similar (but not identical) to [a fixed bug in Xdebug 2.0 on PHP 5.3](http://bugs.xdebug.org/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=00000469) where local variables weren't displayed - that issue was fixed in Xdebug 2.1, though it sounds like you have the opposite problem.